# Google SDK ios 6.0 GMSMutablePath versus Apple Overlays

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Evening all
I can't convert some MKOverlays (created with Apple's documented files KMLParser.h and KMLParser.m) into GMSMutablePaths to create polygon shapes in the new Google Maps SDK for iOS 6.0.
Does anyone have any views?  Is Google Maps simply not user-friendly for dealing with 1000+ polygons / overlays (which appear to be easy to manage, add, delete, remove and 'tap' in apple mapkit)
Thanks in advance for any responses.
Mike